# MongoDB Atlas: Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I've been searching for an answer to this error that I am receiving to my mail:
`Query Targeting: Scanned Objects / Returned has gone above 1000`.

I've checked the [ESR Rules](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/performance-best-practices-indexing) and I could not get a clear answer about this problem.

I am saving in an interval of 3seconds a new document into this collection. And I am also asking for the last document of this collection in an interval of 15 seconds.

I think my code is following the correct way of asking indexes. Can you help me to solve this problem?

This is my python code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient


class ModelOrderBook():    
    @classmethod
    def get_last_orderbook(self, symbol):
        try:
            base, quote, = symbol.split('/')
            sym = base.lower() + "-" + quote.lower()

            client = connect_cluster() # function with the MongoClient connection
            db = client[sym]
            orderbooks = db.orderbooks

            orderbook_id = orderbooks.find().sort([('_id', -1)]).limit(1)
            data = list(orderbook_id)
            client.close()
            return data


        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(e)
            return None
```

Comment: So i'll start by saying this error is a feature given by atlas, I would say most times it's best to just disable it - obviously depending on product needs. They have added it under the assumption that queries that scan over 1k documents are "inefficient" or "not indexed" properly but this assumptions is false for many use cases.

This is 100% a feature that targets new users who don't understand MongoDB so well.

----

Specifically the code snippet you posted is correct, utilizes the index well and in fact this is not the query that is triggering the warning.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert thanks you so much for your answer. As you mentioned, I am triggering a warning when I am receiving an Exception, but since this code is in production I never received an error. I am going to disable it.

Comment: The Query Targeting ratio for this find query should ideally be 1, i.e. scanning 1 object and returning that. So, IMO this may not be the query triggering that alert. Checkout the Profiler tab of your cluster in Atlas and from the Display dropdown there, select "Examined:Returned Ratio". You should then see all the namespaces with the Query Targeting ratios of the slow ops. Go into each and see the "Keys Examined" and "Docs Returned" columns. I think that should give you your suspects.